# Gedmo Tree nested-set with multiple sets

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions, gedmo-tree

We are using the Gedmo package to manage our menus using a nested-set strategy on our web site.

It works, but the problem is that we have several different menus which are referenced via foreign key on our `menu_item` table.

Obviously our `menu_item` table has a self referencing `parent_id`, but is it possible to restrict by another column pointing to another table? i.e. we have several menus, and our Gedmo stuff is on the `menu_item` table. but the `lft` `rgt` stuff considers every row, i just need the rows for that one menu.

Is this possible? And if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it wasn't possible. So I made it possible.

Awaiting the pull request being accepted https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/pull/1877